# How can I create a view on a profile page that shows content related to the user we are viewing

Tags: views

I have a specific "sport user id" that the user provides in order to grab sports results about that user. I want to display their results, which I keep updated and organized programmatically in a cron job, on their profile. The way I would like to link the content would be by keeping the "sport user id" as a field in the result content type and also as a field in the user.

How do I go about creating a filter to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [EVA (Entity Views Attachment)](http://drupal.org/project/eva) module. This allows you to create views, which you can use as a field on any entity (node, profile, user or whatever) you like.

After you created the view, go to "Manage Display" of your content type and move the field in the right position.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple way to show content of a user on their profile page:

- create a view of the content with a contextual filter (called argument in D6) "userid from URL"
- assign the view to a block
- assign that block to show on the user profile (user/uid)